# Can't connect to SQL Server database: Login failed for user 'sa'' 

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlexception

I can't simply connect to my database because of this error

> Login failed for user 'sa'

Consider these lines of code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=arohbi;Initial Catalog=SPADA_FIS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=p@ssword");
conn.Open();
```

After the execution of `conn.Open()` I got this weird error message

> Login failed for user 'sa'.

Last time I used this setup and connection string and it work perfectly but one day when I try to connect this message is the only response. Still I manage to connect using management studio. The connection from the serverdatabase to my local machine work perfectly. Anyone guys knows the answer.

Things get worst this time. Take a look at these images:
[image]

[image]

I used same connection string on both sqlconnection but i was confuse why the other one failed?

Connection string used on both:

```
Data Source=arohbi;Initial Catalog=SPADA_FIS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=espada;Password=p@ssword
```

Comment: This error simply means that either the username/password combo is wrong, or the user does not have access. It could be permissions set incorrectly (possible, but unlikely for an "sa" account), or it could even be that the user was locked out.  Check with the Database Administrator.

Comment: And thanks to @competent_tech for the edit.

Comment: **Please** don't use the sa account. Ever.

Comment: yeah actually i created my own account but still no luck. And what really strange is that. When i try to connect to other database on that server also. I successfully manage to connect but in that case only that database that i can't connect.

Comment: If you are sure that you used the same exact code with the same exact connection string to connect previously, then simple logic would dictate that the problem lies elsewhere.

On the other hand, if you really can connect from management studio then that's a pretty good indication that the problem does lie in your code.  But I suspect there is something different about how you're connecting with management studio.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry guys for asking this kind of question. I overlook that the password is incorrect. Administrator please close this question I already solve the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a three primary reasons that I can think of off the top of my head that would cause this:

1) The sa user's password has expired or is different than what you have specified.

2) The sa user has been disabled, either by being denied permission to connect to the database engine or having the login disabled.

3) Your instance of SQL server is not configured for SQL authentication.

Comment: actually i'm connecting to a remote server. The firewall in that server is on but I already included exception for mssql (port 1433) I don't think that firewall causes this issue but maybe i overlook something

Comment: It's not the firewall.  You wouldn't have gotten far enough to get the error message you got if the firewall were the problem.

Comment: Absollutely not a firewall issue. The firewall would block the connection, not result in a defined in conenction error message. This is SQL Server telling you to get lost, not the firewall swallowing your connection.

Comment: #3 was what did it for me. I reinstalled my SQL Server and it was set by default only to accept Windows authentication, so I had to set it to accept both Windows & SQL auth

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're trying to troubleshoot a problem like this, boil it down to the simplest reproducible case.  Right now, you've got a custom client trying to connect and are interpreting exceptions.  Try connecting with a stock client (i.e. Management Studio) and see what happens.

That said, other answers here are spot on.  Based on the error message that you're getting, either the sa login has been disabled or the password that you're using for it is incorrect.  Contact the administrator of the server to find out how you can connect.